# No items in my loadout

Tags: dota-2

I have received some items after finishing the game. 
I got dazzle,beastmaster and kunkka cosmetics but I checked my loadout,and they aren't there.Is it a Bug?

Comment: what is your dota-2 level?

Comment: Now I'm level 5 ~experience trophy and dota level 1

Comment: Actually you need to set those items...in hero loadout beside the default item you will see your new items. Click on them and you will see an option to set the item.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the match, you can see cosmetics that everyone in the match you played got, with those given items having their usernames under the displayed items.

As you are saying that you got 3 different cosmetics at the end of the match, I presume you thought they were meant for you but they actually weren't.

Comment: @Klouza If the answer is correct, feel free to accept it.